# Spring Security: Step by Step

Tags: encryption, spring-security

I started on Spring a few months back and the Security topic seems the most complex to me. With Acegi moving into Spring I could not find a single tutorial that tells step by step way to add security to a Spring app. Please help me. My requirements are as follows:

- I have several roles in application, they are not hierarchical roles (meaning Role A not necessarily have all roles of Role B etc).
- I want to integrate it to use my own User table where I would store Username, encrypted password (one way encryption) and I want to use either Hibernate or any Spring inbuilt component (read the class name JdbcDaoImpl somewhere, have no clue how to use it though) to access the DB data.
- I probably don't want method level security because I want to use Spring taglibs to selectively show/hide menu items, however there should be way to prohibit unauthorized user to access a page directly through URL.

I don't want ready made code, ([this tutorial](http://www.logicace.com/JavaSample/sample/link?linkId=1) for example confused me to hell, since it doesn't even have Spring security name-space declaration in security.xml), I would appreciate rather a step-by-step guide on how to achieve the above in a Spring2.5/Hibernate3 application using Spring security.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1):

Well without knowing what you've already read here are the articles I used to first start.  Note that a lot of the Acegi Security articles are still relevant, Spring Security uses almost all the concepts from Acegi - the only thing they really added was simplifying [some] configurations - like the auto-config for security situations that exactly fit their use case.

[Securing Java applications with Acegi](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-acegi1/)

[Acegi Security Fundamentals](http://book.javanb.com/Professional-Java-Development-with-the-Spring-Framework/BBL0083.html)

[Pathway from Acegi to Spring Security 2.0](http://java.dzone.com/tips/pathway-acegi-spring-security-)